# Only Image Map be clickable, not div

Tags: html, css

Site: http://tinyurl.com/x983asd93

I need only the image map (top right corner banner) to be clickable, not the entire div/image that it is contained in (sometimes the social icons will be inside of the div, but still visible as they are not covered by the banner). I tried using

```
pointer-events: none
```

on the container div, but that did not solve the problem as it disabled the imagemap href, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div><a href=""><img src="" /></a></div>
```